# how to launch the default editor in R?

Tags: r

Just like you can launch the default browser with `browseURL`, is there a way to launch the default text editor so it opens a given file? Something like

```
editFile("path/to/file.txt")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for `file.edit`:

```
file.edit("path/to/file.txt")
```